# What is the Significance of "Session Token" in AWS temporary credentials?

Tags: jwt, token, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, credentials

I am using AWS temporary credentials obtained in exchange from the Cognito Id token.
The temporary credentials contains Access Key,Secret Key and Session Token.

What is the significance of "Session Token" here and where it can be used?

Answer (score 0):

[Looks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) like it is just used by AWS to validate the credentials:

> When you make a call using temporary security credentials, the call must include a session token, which is returned along with those temporary credentials. **AWS uses the session token to validate the temporary security credentials.**

Comment: I have a suspicion that it contains an encrypted version of the permissions, rather than storing the permissions within AWS. This is because a huge number of temporary credentials could be generated, and avoids the need to store the permissions permanently on a central server. However, that's just a theory.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein interesting!